# Fantastic Four: Another Dimension or Another Planet?

Tags: marvel, fantastic-four-2015

In 2015's Fantastic Four, does the device go to another dimension or another planet? At first, it is referred to as another dimension. But then it is called "Planet Zero" and they act like there is just the planet and nothing else. After that they go back and forth between planet and dimension. And it never really implies that it's another planet in another dimension.

Comment: I know, right? Or both? Is it earth in another dimension? Or a far away planet? Or a far-away planet that’s also in another dimension?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The movie is rather haphazard with it's description of where the team is going, but I think it's intended to be a different dimension.

While they call the place Planet Zero, there are several cases where Fraklin Storm makes reference to "interdimensional travel". Also, the rules of physics on Planet Zero seem slightly different from those of our world, meaning it can't exist anywhere within at least our observable universe.

Thus, the movie was trying to indicate that *Planet* Zero was a planet in an *alternate* dimension, which they never gave a name to.

Comment: Well it feels like Hell, watching it!